# Prove the surface integral of a constant vector field over a surface is equal to the area of the surface times the norm of vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a question as below.

Prove that the surface integral of a constant vector field $F$ over a surface $S$ is equal to the area of $S$ times the norm of $F$, or find counter example.

I think it is true because my textbook gives equation as
$$\int\int_S F \cdot n\ dA$$
where $n$ is the normal vector. I think this is exactly what the question states but how do I prove it?? Or am I wrong??

Comment: False; $F$ must in fact be a non-negative constant multiple of $n$ for this to be true.

Comment: @Nigel Can u explain more?? What does "non-negative constant multiple of $n$" means??

Comment: It means $F=cn$, where $c$ is a non-negative constant. This can be proven with the Schwarz inequality (plus the part that states when equality holds).

Comment: Counterexample: take $ S $ a sphere; then the integral vanishes for any (constant) value of $ \mathbf F $.